# Are there any rules regarding the use of arbitrary integer id's for android controls?

Tags: android, viewgroup

I am writing an app that stores a series of controls in a database to be drawn on the screen at run time.  I would like to assign the database ID as the control ID to make it easier to link any given control to its database record.  Do control ID's need to be unique outside their immediate parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was able to answer my own question.  The reference docs for android.View state: `View IDs need not be unique throughout the tree, but it is good practice to ensure that they are at least unique within the part of the tree you are searching.`  From that I determined that they do not need to be unique.  You would think that google would give this answer in a heart beat, but almost every online referece to View or Control ID talks about the XML attribute.